# access text files stored on ios device

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I am thinking to make an app which would get a list of all text and pdf files stored on an iDevice, like iphones, ipods or ipads.
The user will have an option for dictation of the selected file.
Is it possible to get access to all such files stored in a device???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to list all (text and pdf) files stored on the device. The best you could do is to register your app as one that opens that type of files so that your app can be used to open a file from another app.

You might want to take a look at the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

Comment: Can you please tell me how exactly can i do what you said, i mean how to register my app to open such files???

Answer (score 1):

No, files are stored per app and only accessible by the app that create and maintains the file.

You could tell the system that your app opens specific types of files.